# Nginx - Cloudfront - Lets Encrypt, Stopped Working

Tags: nginx, amazon-cloudfront, lets-encrypt

For some reason as of yesterday, my cloudfront doesn't work. I am constantly getting 502 errors.

I am using Nginx + Lets Encrypt on Ubuntu 16. Everything used to work just fine and I haven't made any changes to the server.

I spent hours looking for an answer and I am really stuck here as I don't know what's going wrong.

I checked the SSL certificate and it shows as valid with no errors. My SSL ciphers that I use in Nginx are:

```
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
```

Doing `curl -i https://mycloudfrontdomain.cloudfront.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4` produces a valid response in my opinion.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 97184
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 31 Oct 2017 08:54:04 GMT
Last-Modified: Sun, 04 Sep 2016 21:11:41 GMT
ETag: "xxx-17ba0"
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 xxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: xxx-id
```

The site loads fine with no errors, if I don't use Cloudfront.

Answer (score 0):

ok changing the chiphers to (without the quotes):

```
ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:RSA+3DES:AES128-SHA:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
```

seems to do the trick. Although I am not quite sure why it used to work fine so far before.